# libfreetype.6.dylib is not loaded (R project using kableExtra; renv for reproducibility)

Tags: r, macos, kableextra, renv

I'm working on [this code](https://github.com/georgialoukatou/weirdchildes), and when I try to knit analyses.Rmd on one of my computers, I get an error specifically due to the attempt to load kableExtra:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘kableExtra’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
> unable to load shared object '/Users/acristia/Library/Application Support/renv/cache/v5/R-4.1/x86_64-apple-darwin17.0/systemfonts/1.0.3/5be9fcf8ef6763e8cb13ab009e273a1d/systemfonts/libs/systemfonts.so':
> dlopen(/Users/acristia/Library/Application Support/renv/cache/v5/R-4.1/x86_64-apple-darwin17.0/systemfonts/1.0.3/5be9fcf8ef6763e8cb13ab009e273a1d/systemfonts/libs/systemfonts.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/freetype/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
> Referenced from: /Users/acristia/Library/Application Support/renv/cache/v5/R-4.1/x86_64-apple-darwin17.0/systemfonts/1.0.3/5be9fcf8ef6763e8cb13ab009e273a1d/systemfonts/libs/systemfonts.so
> Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/freetype/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/acristia/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/lib

I've checked that:

- I have the latest version of R, and Rstudio
- I have the latest version of freetype (also run brew doctor & fixed all warnings there)

Since brew was not installing libfreetype where kableExtra expected it, I did `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/opt/freetype/lib/` and `sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib /usr/local/opt/freetype/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib MacBook-Air:weirdChildes acristia$ ls /usr/local/opt/freetype/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib`

With this, I changed the error from not loaded because it doesn't exist, to not loaded because of wrong architecture:

> tried: '/usr/local/opt/freetype/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')),

(I also saw [a suggestion](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/44570) to do `brew install freetype --universal` but that command is not recognized.

For context: I migrated my mac account to a new laptop, which is intel / monterey, and this probably means that some basic files are not right.

Or potentially, the error arises because makers of kableExtra need to take into account this new architecture. I did find [two open issues](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues?q=libfreetype%20)  mentioning libfreetype in the kableExtra github (one saying the problem was resolved with the latest R version, which is not my case).

For full information on my system, see
[renv-diagnostics.txt](https://github.com/rstudio/renv/files/7853422/renv-diagnostics.txt)

Comment: It sounds as though you are mixing Brew builds of libraries with CRAN builds.  That often leads to incompatibilities.  You should uninstall R and all packages, and reinstall them from CRAN.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68217304/5783745) may be related. (spoiler: it basically says what @user2554330 recommends, i.e. to reinstall everything)

Answer (score 1):

You have linked a copy of freetype from your old Apple Silicon homebrew directory, which is `/opt/homebrew/lib`

For Intel macs, the directory in which homebrew installs the freetype package is `/usr/local/lib`

Intel macs use the architecture `x86_64`

Apple Silicon (M1) uses the `arm64` architecture.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Richard Barber, you could try to create a symbolic link for `libfreetype.6.dylib` in `/usr/local/lib/` with

```
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib /usr/local/liblibfreetype.6.dylib
```

See related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76903720/21565913.