# Why do I need to install the same packages using renv, after having run pkgload::load_all()?

Tags: r, renv

Each time I run `pkgload::load_all()`, I get the message below.

```
> pkgload::load_all()
ℹ Loading my_package
ℹ The packages "dm" and "sf" are required.
✖ Would you like to install them?

1: Yes
2: No
```

After each restart of RStudio, I need to reinstall "dm" and "sf" using "renv" by inserting `1` in the console. And then "sf" will be installed from source.

How could I solve this?

I ran `devtools::install_dev_deps()`. Now I only have the message, but nothing will be installed if I choose the option 1: Yes.

```
> pkgload::load_all()
ℹ Loading my_package
ℹ The packages "dm" and "sf" are required.
✖ Would you like to install them?

1: Yes
2: No

Selection: 1

>
```

```
> devtools::load_all()
ℹ Loading my_package
ℹ The packages "dm" and "sf" are required.
✖ Would you like to install them?

1: Yes
2: No

Selection: 1

> renv::restore()
* The library is already synchronized with the lockfile.
```

```
> renv::install('dm') 
Installing dm [1.0.4] ...
    OK [linked cache]
> devtools::load_all()
ℹ Loading my_package
ℹ The packages "dm" and "sf" are required.
✖ Would you like to install them?

1: Yes
2: No

Selection: 1

>
```

I get the following error when I load the dm or sf packages:

```
> library(dm)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dm’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
  unable to load shared object '/Users/user_name/Library/Application Support/renv/cache/v5/R-4.3/x86_64-apple-darwin20/igraph/1.4.1/a7ef0d811cb66d8be9da0d7b5ab80ded/igraph/libs/igraph.so':
  dlopen(/Users/user_name/Library/Application Support/renv/cache/v5/R-4.3/x86_64-apple-darwin20/igraph/1.4.1/a7ef0d811cb66d8be9da0d7b5ab80ded/igraph/libs/igraph.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: /osxcross/bin/../x86_64-apple-darwin22/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib
Reason: tried: '/osxcross/bin/../x86_64-apple-darwin22/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/osxcross/bin/../x86_64-apple-darwin22/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), '/osxcross/bin/../x86_64-


> library(sf)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sf’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
  unable to load shared object '/Users/user_name/Library/Application Support/renv/cache/v5/R-4.3/x86_64-apple-darwin20/KernSmooth/2.23-20/8dcfa99b14c296bc9f1fd64d52fd3ce7/KernSmooth/libs/KernSmooth.so':
  dlopen(/Users/user_name/Library/Application Support/renv/cache/v5/R-4.3/x86_64-apple-darwin20/KernSmooth/2.23-20/8dcfa99b14c296bc9f1fd64d52fd3ce7/KernSmooth/libs/KernSmooth.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: /osxcross/bin/../x86_64-apple-darwin22/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib
Reason: tried: '/osxcross/bin/../x86_64-apple-darwin22/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/osxcross/bin/../x86_64-apple-darwin22/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib'
```

Comment: Your renv seems broken. What does `renv::status()` say?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I get:

> renv::status()
The following package(s) are installed but not recorded in the lockfile:
      _
  zip   [2.2.2]

Use `renv::snapshot()` to add these packages to your lockfile.

Comment: renv::snapshot(), did you try, let me know the message you got

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to deal with the error messages returned by `library(dm)` and `library(sf)`.

Here is the process of how I solved the problem. I needed to create a symbolic link for `libgfortran.5.dylib` and `libquadmath.0.dylib` in `/usr/local/lib/` (see https://www.kombitz.com/2022/07/28/error-message-usr-local-lib-libgfortran-3-dylib-no-such-file-on-intel-mac-solved/).

```
# Solution for dm ----
devtools::install_github("igraph/rigraph")
renv::install("cynkra/dm")
devtools::load_all()

# After that, I only get 
> devtools::load_all()
* The project may be out of sync -- use `renv::status()` for more details.
ℹ Loading my_package
ℹ The package "sf" is required.
✖ Would you like to install it?

1: Yes
2: No

# For sf ----
brew install pkg-config
brew install gdal

install.packages("rgdal", type = "source", configure.args = c("--with-proj-lib=$(brew --prefix)/lib/", "--with-proj-include=$(brew --prefix)/include/"))

# https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases 
# https://brew.sh
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
brew install gcc

# cf. https://www.kombitz.com/2022/07/28/error-message-usr-local-lib-libgfortran-3-dylib-no-such-file-on-intel-mac-solved/
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/lib/gcc/13/libgfortran.5.dylib /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib

install.packages("rgdal", type = "source", configure.args = c("--with-proj-lib=$(brew --prefix)/lib/", "--with-proj-include=$(brew --prefix)/include/"))
renv::install("rgdal", type = "source", configure.args = c("--with-proj-lib=$(brew --prefix)/lib/", "--with-proj-include=$(brew --prefix)/include/"))

# next error
# libquadmath.0.dylib' (no such file)

# sudo find / -name libquadmath.0.dylib  
# Password:
#/usr/local/gfortran/lib/i386/libquadmath.0.dylib
# /usr/local/gfortran/lib/libquadmath.0.dylib
# /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/lib/gcc/current/libquadmath.0.dylib
# /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/lib/gcc/13/libquadmath.0.dylib


sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/lib/gcc/13/libquadmath.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/libquadmath.0.dylib 


Restarting R session...

devtools::load_all()
> pkgload::load_all()
ℹ Loading my_package
```

Comment: If the error occurs again later, you need to remove the symbolic link you created with the older version of gcc (here 13.1.0) with `rm /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib`and  `rm /usr/local/lib/libquadmath.0.dylib`. Then, create a symbolic link again with the new version of gcc (here 13.2.0 instead of 13.1.0) with `sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/lib/gcc/13/libgfortran.5.dylib /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib`and `sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/lib/gcc/13/libquadmath.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/libquadmath.0.dylib`.

Answer (score 3):

This message:

> Reason: tried: '/osxcross/bin/../x86_64-apple-darwin22/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/osxcross/bin/../x86_64-apple-darwin22/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), '/osxcross/bin/../x86_64-

implies that you're currently using Posit Package Manager, and unfortunately the binaries delivered on PPM on macOS currently have an issue for packages which link to `libgfortran.5.dylib`. The team is actively investigating and we're hoping to have the issue resolved soon.

As a workaround, you can switch back to the CRAN repositories with:

```
options(repos = c(CRAN = "https://cloud.r-project.org"))
```

and then reinstall the affected packages. If you're using `renv`, after setting the repositories, you can run:

```
renv::snapshot()
```

to update the lockfile.

EDIT: A fix has now been pushed to Posit Package Manager, and the x86_64 macOS binaries should no longer have this issue. A similar fix for RStudio is being investigated in https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/13085; the RStudio team hopes to have a fix in the next RStudio release (Desert Sunflower; targeted for 2023-09).

Answer (score 0):

why you are using the `pkgload::load_all()` instead of `devtools::load_all()`

please try to install the `dm` and `sf` with renv

Comment: Thank you. Please see my edited message above. It did not change anything.

Comment: could you please try to install the dm and sf via renv::install('dm')

Comment: I did but nothing changed. See the edited description above.

Comment: within your project in any of the R code please call library(dm) and then run the code and then run the renv::snapshot() so that the lock file will get updated and we can avoid that message

Comment: I get an error when I load dm or sf. See above.

Comment: i dont see  you have updated the lock file, did you run the renv::snapshot() after this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254902/discussion-between-layal-and-jkatam).